# rm command to be use with xargs to exclude some folders having space in the name

Tags: shell, scripting, solaris

In one directory I have around 50 files and folders that includes some folders with space in their names. I want to delete some folders using ls, grep and xargs command but not able to delete the folders with space in their names and shows exception. Can anyone help? Using a Solaris OS.
I tried below for deleting everything except $files

ls | grep -v "$files" | xargs rm

and when I tried below command it deletes everything including $files which I dont want.

ls | grep -v "$files" | xargs rm --*\ *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using non-standard extensions, and assuming your shell implements `while read ...`, this also should work:

```
ls | grep -v "$files" | while read filename; do
    rm "$filename"
done
```

The quotes around `$filename` are critical.  Without the quotes, the argument will be split on any spaces that may be in the name.

Note also that won't delete a directory - as others have mentioned, you need `rm -r` - or `rmdir` - to do that.  But `rm -r` will delete a directory *and everything in it*.  `rmdir` by default won't delete a non-empty directory.

You probably should run a test first with something like

```
ls | grep -v "$files" | while read filename; do
    ls -ld "$filename"
done
```

Use the `-ld` options to `ls` to be sure you're getting the correct file, and also to *not* list directory contents if the file name passed happens to be a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Unix-like systems allow any characters to appear in file names with the exception of the ASCII NUL character and the slash. Slashes can occur in path names (as the directory separator) but not in the names of actual directory entries. This means that the list of files that `xargs` reads could in fact contain white space characters – spaces, tabs and newline characters. Since by default, `xargs` assumes that the list of files it is reading uses white space as an argument separator, it cannot correctly handle the case where a filename actually includes white space. This makes the default behavior of `xargs` almost useless for handling arbitrary data.

To solve this problem, GNU findutils introduced the ‘-print0’ action for find. This uses the ASCII NUL character to separate the entries in the file list that it produces. This is the ideal choice of separator since it is the only character that cannot appear within a path name. The ‘-0’ option to `xargs` makes it assume that arguments are separated with ASCII NUL instead of white space. It also turns off another misfeature in the default behavior of `xargs`, which is that it pays attention to quote characters in its input. Some versions of `xargs` also terminate when they see a lone ‘_’ in the input, but GNU find no longer does that (since it has become an optional behavior in the Unix standard).

So, putting find -print0 together with xargs -0 we get this command:

```
find /var/tmp/stuff -mtime +90 -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm
```

The result is an efficient way of proceeding that correctly handles all the possible characters that could appear in the list of files to delete. This is good news. However, there is, as I'm sure you're expecting, also more bad news. The problem is that this is not a portable construct; although other versions of Unix (notably BSD-derived ones) support ‘-print0’, it's not universal.

Comment: `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0` are non-standard GNU extensions.  You mention GNU utilities but don't make it clear that non-GNU implementations likely lack those extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove folders with the `rm` command unless you use the `-r` option (recursive). I'm assuming then that you want to delete individual files, not whole directories.

In any case, you can process files and directories with arbitray names with the standard `find` commands which is always available with Solaris. Neither `xargs` nor GNU specific extensions are necessary.

Here is an example. All files except those with the .jpg or .java suffix, and those having *keepme* in their names will be kept, all remaining files will be processed:

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.jpg" ! -name "*keepme*" ! -name "*.java" -exec echo rm {} +
```

Remove the `echo` command if you want the file removal to actually be performed.